# PEAP authentication failure using wpa_supplicant

Tags: wpa-supplicant, wpa2-eap

I have an embedded Linux system, kernel 4.1.18, running wpa_supplicant v2.5, trying to connect to a PEAP network. My PC can connect fine but the Linux system cannot and I'm stuck figuring out what I'm missing.

My wpa_supplicant.conf file

```
network={
    ssid="prod"
    scan_ssid=1
    mode=0
    key_mgmt=WPA-EAP
    eap=PEAP
    password="blah"
    identity="blah"
}
```

Some log output:

```
> scan
OK
<3>CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED
<3>CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-RESULTS
<3>SME: Trying to authenticate with 64:a0:e7:da:f1:a5 (SSID='prod' freq=2412 MHz)
<3>Trying to associate with 64:a0:e7:da:f1:a5 (SSID='prod' freq=2412 MHz)
<3>Associated with 64:a0:e7:da:f1:a5
<3>CTRL-EVENT-EAP-STARTED EAP authentication started
<3>CTRL-EVENT-EAP-STATUS status='started' parameter=''
<3>CTRL-EVENT-EAP-PROPOSED-METHOD vendor=0 method=25
<3>CTRL-EVENT-EAP-STATUS status='accept proposed method' parameter='PEAP'
<3>CTRL-EVENT-EAP-METHOD EAP vendor 0 method 25 (PEAP) selected
<3>CTRL-EVENT-EAP-STATUS status='completion' parameter='failure'
<3>CTRL-EVENT-EAP-FAILURE EAP authentication failed
<3>Authentication with 64:a0:e7:da:f1:a5 timed out.
<3>CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=64:a0:e7:da:f1:a5 reason=3 locally_generated=1
<3>CTRL-EVENT-SSID-TEMP-DISABLED id=7 ssid="prod" auth_failures=1 duration=10 reason=AUTH_FAILED
```

scan_results output:

```
64:a0:e7:da:f1:a5       2412    -55     [WPA2-EAP-CCMP][ESS]    prod
```

Looking at a verbose output from wpa_supplicant it looks like I'm timing out during authentication. Any way to increase the timeout?

```
21973.688487: nl80211: Association request send successfully
21974.032784: nl80211: Event message available
21974.033152: nl80211: Drv Event 20 (NL80211_CMD_DEL_STATION) received for wlan0
21974.033240: nl80211: Delete station 64:a0:e7:da:f1:a5
21974.062289: nl80211: Event message available
21974.062594: nl80211: Drv Event 38 (NL80211_CMD_ASSOCIATE) received for wlan0
21974.062683: nl80211: MLME event 38; timeout with 64:a0:e7:da:f1:a5
21974.062776: wlan0: Event ASSOC_TIMED_OUT (15) received
21974.062845: wlan0: SME: Association timed out
21974.062927: wlan0: Radio work 'sme-connect'@0xb8960 done in 0.438536 seconds
21974.062984: Added BSSID 64:a0:e7:da:f1:a5 into blacklist
21974.063102: wlan0: Another BSS in this ESS has been seen; try it next
21974.063159: BSSID 64:a0:e7:da:f1:a5 blacklist count incremented to 2
21974.063223: wlan0: Blacklist count 1 --> request scan in 100 ms
21974.063284: wlan0: Setting scan request: 0.100000 sec
21974.063353: wlan0: State: ASSOCIATING -> DISCONNECTED
21974.063404: nl80211: Set wlan0 operstate 0->0 (DORMANT)
```

Comment: Is it EDUROAM, by any chance?

Comment: No, it's not EDUROAM.